# Criteria criterion Obj = Expression.Eq("Record Source", "GLOBAL");

Tags: nhibernate

Criteria criterion Obj = Expression.Eq("Record Source", "GLOBAL");

is this equal to select query? what is RecordSource and Global? is there any other method rather than using Icriteria and please give any other method

Answer (score 1):

This is equal to WHERE clause of SQL. The complete query with criteria could look like this:

```
IList<Track> tracks = session.CreateCriteria<Track>()
.Add(Expression.Eq("Album", album0))
.List<Track>();
```

where "Album" property name of Track entity and album0 property value.
NH supports a lot of quering methods: criteria, HQL, Linq, QueryOver, native SQL.
The simplest, imho, Linq.

```
session.Query<Track>.Where(t => t.Album.Name = "...").ToList();
```